# What is the most effective way to passively monitor users in a complex web-based system?

Tags: data-analysis, data-collection

Focus is on interface use patterns, not on raw page views.

Comment: Your question (and others you've posted) sound like a professor who is giving a homework. :-)

Comment: @Hisham - I was thinking the opposite - parroting questions asked of him by a professor.

Comment: Um. Sit next to them and watch them?

Comment: @Rahul: By "passively" I mean that they user is not aware they are being watched.

Comment: @Hisham: The questions are for me. Glad you like them though... :-)

Comment: @blunders So are you asking in regards to testing or because you want to spy on people?

Comment: @Rahul: Not following you questions, are you saying a system like Tealeaf's is spying on people?

Comment: @blunders Well, you want a system to watch people without them being aware of being watched... the dictionary tells me that's called "spying". I don't have a problem with that being your goal, just trying to figure out whether that *is* your goal :)

Comment: @Rahul: Feel free to call it whatever you want, I would never use that world to describe a legal method of observing users. That's like saying logging cookies, IPs, etc. is spying, it's not.

Comment: @blunders: While using cookies may be considered "standard operating procedure" by some (now ask why many people do not allow them), logging them or an IP is not and is spying when you do not make your users aware (tell them directly and not on some hidden page) that it is being done.

Comment: @Marjan - in no way is logging cookies and IP addresses of your users is not spying. Where do you get that from? I don't know a site out there that doesn't log visitors' IP addresses.

Comment: @Charles: Standard Operating Procedure perhaps. But still spying if your users/visitors aren't aware of it though. It may be hidden in a privacy statement, but a site should still always disclose it is using cookies to make it work. No two ways about it.

Comment: @Marjan - you clearly have absolutely no idea what you are talking about. Why don't you go ask your developers if they use cookies for your website? I can guarantee to you that they are, and I'm sure they aren't notifying the users of that. There is absolutely no reason, legal or otherwise that that is needed.

Comment: @Charles: Obviously. Apparently you know a lot more about me than I do. For your information: I don't have developers, I am a developer. It might be wiser not to make such blatantly uninformed statements about anybody. Also, I don't know and don't care what part of the world you are from, but legalities aren't the same everywhere.

Comment: @Charles: and even when something is standard operating procedure and perhaps even legal, that doesn't in itself make it moral, ethical or desired.

Comment: @Marjan Venema: I clicked your profile link, which appears to have a link to a website of yours (http://www.bjmsoftware.com), you'll notice after loading it that it uses a cookie and likely logs IPs (you're using Google Analytics) -- also the site appears to have no privacy policy anywhere on the site informing users of this. Care to comment on why this appears to be the case? CC:@Charles Boyung

Comment: Because I am lazy. Doesn't mean I am not spying...

Comment: (By the way: the privacy policy is on my todo list. Just haven't gotten round to it for a long time, and may not for a similar period of time. Still doesn't make it right though)

Comment: @Marjan Venema: Ok, just making sure I wasn't misunderstanding something.

Comment: @blunders: no problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effective but expensive... Checkout http://www.tealeaf.com/.  It allows you to see the fine details of use.

You can also setup most analytics systems, like Ominture or Coremetrics, to track every single selection (takes a lot of work though).

Comment: Tealeaf is the sort of solution I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[ClickTale](http://www.clicktale.com/) lets your record visits and then watch them back like a video, including mouse moves, scrolling, etc. The first time I saw it, I felt a bit odd that I was being tracked in so much detail - so some users might not like it, but it should do what you want.

They offer mouse-move heatmaps as well, which (they claim) [correlate highly with eye-tracking](http://blog.clicktale.com/2010/10/14/eye-tracking-vs-mouse-tracking/) data.

It's also quite expensive for a web monitoring tool.